# AndroidStudio Plugin building and grabbing apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, plugins, intellij-idea

I am making an AndroidStudio Plugin, I wish if it's possible to build then grab the Java.io.File instance of that built Apk.

If its also possible, adding a Run option such as "Run on My Dev World" for example, so I would run that apk in a customized way. Pretty much adding a new run method, as the same way run options do for now, you can select if you want to run an Emulator or USB Device, I wish I could add one more option to run on my way on my custom service. Would that be possible ?

Again, thanks for the attention !

Best Regards !